# Calculate the average promotion rate of an indivdual in society?

Tags: probability, statistics, simulation

Imagine a hierarchy with $N$ layers (maybe $N=6$, say). And under each person except the bottom layer there are $M$ people ($M=30$, say). A person works for a length of time $T$ ($T=50$ years, say). After this time they retire. If they are a boss, one of the $M$ random employees gets promoted. Also, a new person joins the hierarchy at the bottom. Seed this simulation with random aged people and let this simulation run for a while. After it has run for a while a new person joins the hierarchy at the bottom.

What is the probability $P(X)$ that within a lifetime this person reaches level $X$? What is the probability $P(N)$ that (s)he reaches all the way to the top? i.e. becomes president?

Bonus questions: What is the average age of the president over time? And average age of people on each level of the hierarchy? How long on average does someone stay president until they retire?

My instincts are that the majority of people don't get promoted very far. And also that the president is always quite old.

Is there a name for this type of problem?

Edit: Running some simulations I seem to get that for $N=6$, and $T=50$ a president stays on average for about 10 years it seems to not depend too much on M which is odd. In fact I get an empirical estimate of roughly $T/N$ years for an average presidential term from simulations. Can this be explained? Only that it would take longer for a president to make it up more layers and so have a shorter time in office until retirement. I guess this makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean when you ask for a "name for this type of problem"? Are you asking to google for other problems that are similar in some way? What are the important characteristics of the problem that confuse you?

Comment: For instance is it a Monte Carlo problem? Or a Bayesian problem? Or a matrix problem? Or a Markov problem? I don't know what kind of problem it is! It has probability and dynamics and simulation. Should it be solved with differential equations? Except by simulating it on a computer. Perhaps its been solved before under a different name?

Comment: The problem clearly asks you to simulate it on a computer. Did you do that? Once you do, you can estimate the probabilities empirically from the simulation.

Comment: But I want to solve it with math

Comment: You can write the transition as a markov chain on an appropriate state space. Finding the steady state of the chain lets you answer questions about the average age of people at each level. Answering the other questions exactly seems a bit subtle, but maybe some tools from markov chain theory make it easier.

Comment: Interestingly if my tests are true. It says that a person is has more chance to become president the more layers there are keeping population equal. Since the president will have less time in office. A more hierarchical society is more fair society!

Comment: What is $L$ in the last paragraph?  We haven't seen it before.

Comment: Sorry should be N for layers.